# Lighttpd Multiple Redirects

Tags: redirect, lighttpd

I have two redirects in place for my app,

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^(.*)$" {
  url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)\.(markdown|md)$" => "http://%1/$1.html")
}

$HTTP["host"] =~ "^www\.(.*)$" {
  url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "http://%1/$1" )
}
```

One redirects markdown or md extension to html version, other redirects www to non www. But one overrides the other depending on which one comes latter.

Comment: Yes, that is expected behavior. Is there a question in here?

Answer (score 0):

If you flip the order of the redirects, then you should reach the desired result.

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^www\.(.*)$" {
      url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "http://%1/$1" )
}
else $HTTP["host"] =~ "^(.*)$" {
      url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)\.(markdown|md)$" => "http://%1/$1.html")
}
```

**CASE 1**

```
1.  http://www.agilityspeaks.com/test.md redirects to http://agilityspeaks.com/test.md
2.  http://agilityspeaks.com/test.md then redirects to http://agilityspeaks.com/test.html
```

**CASE 2**

```
1.  http://agilityspeaks.dom/test.md redirects to http://agilityspeaks.com/test.html
```

I haven't tested this, but don't see why this solution above wouldn't work.  Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You can check out below given examples, i have given 4 diff senario on lightty to perform redirect.

```
 $SERVER["socket"] == "10.0.0.14:80" {
           server.name = "example.com"
    server.document-root = "/data/logs/"
    accesslog.filename = "/logs/www/access_log"
    server.errorlog = "/logs/www/error_log"


      url.redirect = (

"^/(.*)" => "http://tikejhya.com/$1", 
    ""       => "http://tikejhya.com/",

            "^(.*[^/])$" => "$1/", --> adding trailing slash

            "^(.*.txt)" => "$1"    or --> removing trailing slash
            )
    }
```

Hope this helps